# How to get a list of Nuget packages used by multiple microservices

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

We have dozens of microservices and need to keep track of the list of Nuget packages used by each and update these packages at regular intervals for compliance. Is there a tool out there that could scan multiple solutions/projects and give us an overview of package installations?

Comment: Hi friend, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the installed nuget packages' info each solution.

Open each solution `xxx.sln` file with **VS IDE**. And then enter **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**, then type:

```
Get-Package | Select-Object Id, Version, ProjectName
```

If your sln file are all new-sdk projects(`net core` or `net standard`), you could run

```
 dotnet list xxx\xxx.sln package
```

under **CMD** or **Package Manage Console** to get the info.